# Tweet clustering after semantic analysis

Tags: python, nlp, cluster-analysis, k-means, tweets

I want to cluster a set of tweets. I have already retrieved the tweets, cleaned them up, applied a Naïve Bayes classifier to them and divided them into two files, positive and negative. Finally, I have done the following to search for similarities  between each tweet:

```
  with open("positive.txt", "r") as pt:
        lines = pt.readlines()
        for lineA in lines:
            vectorA = text_to_vector(lineA)
            for lineB in lines:
                vectorB = text_to_vector(lineB)
                cosine = get_cosine(vectorA, vectorB)
                print lineA, "\n", lineB, "\n", "Cosine:", cosine
```

Now this is supposed to measure the similarity of each sentence relative to the other, I was thinking the next step might be to add up the values for the all the phrases so add up all the cosine values for the relation of sentence n to all the sentence, and after doing this, plot them and apply something like KMeans, I'm not entirely sure I'm taking a correct approach here, so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: There are many choices, but based on my experience they all do not work on Tweets. You have duplicates (easy), near-duplicates (more challenging, at scale). But clusters - too much garbage in Twitter to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a set of documents that you want to cluster (based on their content), the easiest option is to use the tool [Cluto](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/cluto/cluto/overview). You basically have to run it in two steps.

The first step is to execute the program *doc2mat* which takes an input file that is supposed to contain all the documents, one document in each line. The doc2mat program will write out a matrix file, comprised of the tf-idf vector representation for each document.

You then need to feed in this matrix file to the program *vcluster* which will produce the clustering results. You can also evaluate the clustering results, if you input a reference class file to vcluster.

Comment: Could I apply k-means after I perform the first step?  Also cant seem to find vcluster around care to provide a link? Finally can you go into detail regarding your last statement dont think I fully understand ill try this out and verify the answer as soon as I see it's what im looking for!

Comment: Yes... u can apply K-means... Go through the documentation of vcluster... one of the parameters is takes is 'clmethod' which for K-means should be 'direct'... go through this manual http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/fetch/sw/cluto/manual.pdf